# Is there any way to install slapd in ubuntu with auto-configured TLS?

Tags: server, openldap

I have found (as it seems to me) that some case of installing slapd is also configured TLS for a new installed slapd service.

But unfortunately I cannot found a distro version (trusty|xenial|...) which will configuring slapd with TLS for me now.

I could be wrong. It seems that I saw this feature, but it does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to configure it yourself.